# Debugging DB2 Session

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpg

I'm just the unfortunate sole debugging an iSeries/RPG/SQL issue... (I'm not an RPG expert)

I have a program which contains temporary tables declared on DB2 on the iSeries. The temporary tables are declared in a session, so when I run the application and debug the RPG via a terminal on the iSeries (I presume this is the right terminology?) Anyway, I'm effectively in two different sessions.

The SQL I am looking at does something like this...

```
select blah from SESSION/#temp_table left join #real_table left join _to_many_other_tables
```

While I can query the "real table" fine, I can't see the contents of the SESSION table... so how would I go about querying a table in a different session ?? Presumably SESSION/#temp_table is something I could query by doing something like select * from 123123/#temp_table, but how would I know what the other session id/name/variable/access token looks like?

Comment: As commented below, I couldn't just look at the SQL that generated the temporary table. On DB2 I think you can do this using syntax like "select dataX, dataY from table(RPG_PROGRAM_X([...]) as x, tabley as y where x.id = y.id [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [STRSRVJOB](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/evfclmst297.htm) to debug another job, but this probably won't let you query that job's QTEMP.  Traditionally, midrange programmers debug jobs like these interactively.  Sign on to a green screen session and CALL the program you want to debug.

Between [STRDBG](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/cl/strdbg.htm), [STRISDB](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/cl/strisdb.htm), the [system debugger](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzamq/rzamqmain.htm) and the SEP facility found in [RDi](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/49773f8f-a20d-4816-86f2-44a2d862dbc1/entry/rational_developer_for_i_v9_0_and_rational_developer_for_aix_and_linux_v9_0_are_now_available?lang=en), there are many options to tackle the [debugging problem](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/c0925075213.htm).  Additionally, the open source [DBG400](http://www.dbg400.net/foswiki/bin/view/DBG400/BreakPgm) might be something to look at.

**EDIT:**
The problem is a difficult one.  It looks like this is a client/server type app.  When writing an app like this, I usually put a debug switch into it so I can log what's happening for debugging purposes.  Stored procedures on DB2 for i can be implemented purely in SQL, or they can call out to an HLL like RPG for the implementation.

If your SPs are external, say RPG, then add some code that will copy the temporary files to a real library on the system.  Implementing it as a system() or QCMDEXC call is not very intrusive to the existing program code.  You can turn it on and off with a data area - again, very unintrusive, but you can set the debug state from outside the application.

If your SPs are SQL, I'd modify them to write a duplicate of the temporary file in a real library.  Say there's a CREATE TABLE QTEMP/TEMP001 WITH DATA ...  Add a CREATE TABLE DEBUGLIB/TEMP001 WITH DATA ...  If you wanted to, you could key this extra code on a special 'debug' user profile, although that might require some security changes on the IBM i side.

Comment: Yes, I've used STRDBG from a greenscreen, but that doesn't put me in the jobs QTemp or Session. To debug it using a call I'd have to write a wrapper and adjust the arguments for each call as each call builds the data in the tables which is arduous.

Comment: Typically, a process that builds temporary files is a batch process and is usually already scripted by a CL program or a CL script (via SBMDBJOB).  How does your job get kicked off?

Comment: Its interactive, so a windows application kicks off the job. A number of temp tables are built to summarize some data and then its the joins on these temp tables that produces a result... which is fine but it produces the wrong result and I can't see the data in the temp tables... (Not my code, its just fallen to me to fix!)

Comment: I missed the edit before, but it looks like this will do what I'm after. I'll do some testing next week. Thanks

Comment: @0909EM it shouldn't be necessary to see the data in the temp table. You should only need the SQL statement that builds the temp table. With a copy of that, you could build a copy of the result set. That means a need to see exactly what the statement is or what the variable values are that build the statement. If you're running against i 6.1 or later with recent cume and DB2 PTF groups, [**Data Studio 4.1.0.1**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-debugger-db2-i/index.html) provides SQL debug for SQL stored procs. It takes setup and practice, but works.

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't SQL only that populated the temp table. It was a little while ago and I'm not an iSeries expert, but from memory the temporary table was created from a mix of selecting information directly from clunky old RPG programs and from DB2 tables... on an iSeries you can do something funky by declaring an rpg program and then declaring an sql statement that runs over that RPG program - its inefficient but the company I work for have a preference for RPG over SQL. The syntax is then something like "select [...] from table(rpgprogram(params)) as x, db2table as y where [...]"

Comment: For clarity, the syntax FROM TABLE() is called a User Defined Table Function.  One can define a UDTF in pure SQL, or one can use an HLL like RPG to return the UDTF.  There is nothing inherently inefficient about doing it this way, and in fact is a reasonable  way to make the legacy database available to modern SQL-using tools.